# Multidimensional array sorting by certain ID

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array what look like this example:

```
$save[0]['id']='147';
$save[0]['record1']='car';
$save[0]['record2']='road';

$save[1]['id']='147';
$save[1]['record1']='truck';
$save[1]['record2']='wheel';

$save[2]['id']='155';
$save[2]['record1']='cat';
$save[2]['record2']='food';

$save[3]['id']='156';
$save[3]['record1']='baby';
$save[3]['record2']='pacifier';

$save[4]['id']='156';
$save[4]['record1']='mom';
$save[4]['record2']='shirt';
```

It need to be sorted and listed like this:

> - ID 147:
>
>   - car|road
>   - truck|whell
> - ID 155:
>
>   - cat|food
> - ID 156:
>
>   - baby|pacifier
>   - mom|shirt

I realy stack on this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? You're missing some closing quotes in some of your array identifiers.

Comment: Oh my mistake on writing - fixed. I whant to display content like on example. To use list of ID's and in the next level all content of that ID.

Comment: Some ideas to change the display of array and sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic implemntation... Ther is best anwser certainly ;)

```
<?php

$save[0]['id']=147;
$save[0]['record1']='car';
$save[0]['record2']='road';

$save[1]['id']=147;
$save[1]['record1']='truck';
$save[1]['record2']='wheel';

$save[2]['id']=155;
$save[2]['record1']='cat';
$save[2]['record2']='food';

$save[3]['id']=156;
$save[3]['record1']='baby';
$save[3]['record2']='pacifier';

$save[4]['id']=156;
$save[4]['record1']='mom';
$save[4]['record2']='shirt';


$arr=array();

$i=0;
foreach($save as $k) {
    $i++;
    if(!isset($arr[$k['id']])) {
        $arr[$k['id']]=array();     
    }
    $arr[$k['id']][$i][] = $k['record1'];
    $arr[$k['id']][$i][] = $k['record2'];
}

foreach($arr as $k=>$values) {
    foreach($values as $kk => $v) {
        $arr[$k][$kk] = implode('|', $v);
    }
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($arr as $id => $values) {
    echo "<li>ID $id</li>";
    if(count($values)) {
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($values as $value) {
            echo "<li>$value</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

echo '<pre>'.print_r($arr,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!!! GREAT JOB!!! This is what I need. Very interesting approach. Thank you mate!

Comment: Thanks a lot... I think there is a better method... But it's work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `array_multisort`.
Demo Code:

```
$array = array(
    array("id" => 115, "record1" => "cat", "food"),
    array("id" => 215, "record1" => "cat2", "food2"),
    array("id" => 22, "record1" => "cat3", "food3")
);

$sort = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $sort[$key] = $values["id"];
}

array_multisort($sort, SORT_NUMERIC, $array);

var_dump($array);
```